# Rails Dynamic Timestamp

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, timestamp

I want to put Dynamic Timestamp in my Rails application where, when the page is updated, it shows that last time it was updated in different pages.

Currently, I am able to put a timestamp using Javascript, but it gives the same date on every page, when the site is updated.

Comment: What do you mean page is updated? Are you talking about the content of the page? If so, how are you updating the content of the page?

Comment: By updating page I mean write some code, push on Git hub, pull code in AMI and deploy it. I am not talking about the page content, I am talking about updating Timestamp on a particular page, whenever there is a change in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this in your view:

```
<%= File.ctime __FILE__ %>
```

That should give you the last time the file (where you placed this code) was modified.